# If $|E|_e =0$, then $\{x+y\mid x,y\in E\}$ may be non-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $|E|_e =0$, then $\{x+y\mid x,y\in E\}$ may be non-measurable. How to construct such a set?

First, I think about Cantor set, but I have no idea.

Can you tell me some suggestion,thank you!!!

Comment: Is $\|\cdot \|_e$ any measure or does it have to be Lebesgue?

Comment: Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$; Consider a Vitali set $\mathcal{V}$ in $[0,1]$ constructed by the usual way.

Next consider the set $E = \{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathcal{V} \} \cup \{(0,y) \mid y\in \mathcal{V} \}$. This is the embedding of $\mathcal{V}$ in the vertical and horizontal axes. It is obvious $m^2(E) = 0$ since $E$ is contained in the union of 2 straight lines,and each of them is of measure $0$.

Now, $E+E$  is not measurable.

This is because:
$$E+E = \{(x,y) \mid x,y \in \mathcal{V} \} \cup N$$ where $N= \{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathcal{V}+\mathcal{V} \} \{(0,y) \mid y \in \mathcal{V}+\mathcal{V} \}$ is a null set (by the same reasoning $E$ is) and therefore it is not of great interest, since the measurability of $E+E$ is not affected by this set. We are left to analyze the set $S =\{(x,y) \mid x,y \in \mathcal{V} \}$.

$S$ is not measurable, and this is shown the same way we show $\mathcal{V}$ is not measurable.

Comment: I figure out.Thank you!!!

Comment: @ChihChiaChang, frankly, i'm still thinking about the case of $\mathbb{R}$